# recursive calls. how and why return of max value? (standard ML of new jersey)

Tags: sml, smlnj

This is terrible code, but it works. I just wonder how this recursive call can tell which number is the biggest/max? Try explain as if I was 7 years old :)

```
fun badmax (xs : int list)=
    if null xs
    then 0
    else if null (tl xs)
    then hd xs
    else if hd xs > badmax(tl xs)
    then hd xs
    else badmax(tl xs)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. It finds out which number is bigger by using the `>` operator.

Comment: Why not execute the code by hand and see what happens? Try to understand all the functions works (`null`, `tl`, and `hd`).

Comment: What aspect of it do you need explained?

Answer (score 2):

Read [`null`](http://sml-family.org/Basis/list.html#SIG:LIST.null:VAL), [`tl`](http://sml-family.org/Basis/list.html#SIG:LIST.tl:VAL), and [`hd`](http://sml-family.org/Basis/list.html#SIG:LIST.hd:VAL) first. Some hints to get you started.

```
fun badmax (xs : int list)=
    if null xs  <- If the list is empty, return 0
    then 0
    else if null (tl xs)  <- If there is nothing returned by `null (tl xs)`, 
                             we will return hd xs.
                             Q: Are you sure there is anything left in `hd xs`? 
                             Note that if there is nothing left, calling
                             `hd xs` will raise exception. How can you be sure? 
    then hd xs
    else if hd xs > badmax(tl xs) Q: What are we comparing here? 
                                     Think about what does `badmax(tl xs)` 
                                     return and why would we return `hd xs` 
                                     if the condition is satisfied.
                                  Again, ask why `hd xs` and `tl xs` are legal.
    then hd xs
    else badmax(tl xs)            Q: Why would we want to return `badmax(tl xs)`
```

Comment: @pad no problem. Welcome to the world of SML :P

Answer (score 1):

The greatest element in the empty list is not 0.

You could handle the special case of the empty list using an exception:

```
fun max [] = raise Empty
  | max [x] = x
  | max (x::xs) = case max xs of
                    y => if x > y then x else y
```

You can run that by substituting expressions one at a time (like math):

```
max [3,9,7]
  ~> case max [9,7] of y1 => if 3 > y1 then 3 else y1
  ~> case (case max [7] of y2 => if 9 > y2 then 9 else y2) of
       y1 => if 3 > y1 then 3 else y1
  ~> case (case 7 of y2 => if 9 > y2 then 9 else y2) of
       y1 => if 3 > y1 then 3 else y1
  ~> case (if 9 > 7 then 9 else 7) of
       y1 => if 3 > y1 then 3 else y1
  ~> case 9 of y1 => if 3 > y1 then 3 else y1
  ~> if 3 > 9 then 3 else 9
  ~> 9
```

The intermediate results look complicated because of *case-of*. You could use *let-in-end* to define the function in a similar way, but the intermediate results would probably be equally confusing.

```
fun max [] = raise Empty
  | max [x] = x
  | max (x::xs) = let val y = max xs
                  in if x > y then x else y
                  end
```

There's a library function called `Int.max` that takes a tuple of two integers and returns the bigger integer. It makes the code and the intermediate results look much neater:

```
fun max [] = raise Empty
  | max [x] = x
  | max (x::xs) = Int.max (x, max xs)
```

You can run the function "by hand" to see how it works:

```
max [3,9,7,5,6]
  ~> Int.max (3, max [9,7,5,6])
  ~> Int.max (3, Int.max (9, max [7,5,6]))
  ~> Int.max (3, Int.max (9, Int.max (7, max [5,6])))
  ~> Int.max (3, Int.max (9, Int.max (7, Int.max (5, max [6]))))
  ~> Int.max (3, Int.max (9, Int.max (7, Int.max (5, 6))))
  ~> Int.max (3, Int.max (9, Int.max (7, 6)))
  ~> Int.max (3, Int.max (9, 7))
  ~> Int.max (3, 9)
  ~> 9
```

Still, the longer the list, the longer the call-stack.

So you could write a tail-recursive version:

```
(* Keeps the current largest integer in an extra argument, y *)
fun maxhelp ([], y) = y
  | maxhelp (x::xs, y) = maxhelp (xs, Int.max (x, y))

fun max [] = raise Empty
  | max (x::xs) = maxhelp (xs, x)
```

When you run that by hand for the same input:

```
max [3,9,7,5,6]
  ~> maxhelp ([9,7,5,6], 3)
  ~> maxhelp ([7,5,6], Int.max (9, 3))
  ~> maxhelp ([7,5,6], 9)
  ~> maxhelp ([5,6], Int.max (7, 9))
  ~> maxhelp ([5,6], 9)
  ~> maxhelp ([6], Int.max (5, 9))
  ~> maxhelp ([6], 9)
  ~> maxhelp ([], Int.max (6, 9))
  ~> maxhelp ([], 9)
  ~> 9
```

In the first version, `Int.max` was called with a number as one operand and a recursive call as the other, and the recursive call depended on yet another recursive call before any of the `Int.max`es could be resolved.

In the second version, `Int.max` is called with two numbers and the result is stored in an argument to `maxhelp`. So when `maxhelp` makes its recursive call, it depends on `Int.max` being resolved rather than the other way around. That's neater because `Int.max` isn't recursive.

Comment: thanks, i need to think about that one :) Im new in programming so im only taking baby steps.

Comment: Hi. I updated the example to some entirely different ones. I'm sorry for not explaining anything.